# New (bi-fold) doors that are peeling(?) on the corners

Tags: repair, doors

I've purchased a few bi-fold doors from Lowe's, and now the corners of the doors all look like this (https://imgur.com/a/vduq84h) after a few weeks. I know this is only going to get worse, and was wondering if there's a way to prevent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your pic shows is extremely minor.

The outer facing of the door is Masonite. It's a soft wood byproduct that has a harder coating on one side but is easily compressed or damaged along the edges. It may have gotten a bit swollen when the moisture from the paint got around it.

That bit of fracturing is actually common on the corners where the doors may have been bumped. Usually it is un-noticeable except for an unusual close examination.  If you prefer you can apply a dab of caulking around any area like that, similar to applying an ointment to a wound.  Wipe the extra caulk from the edges and you're good.  it is not likely to keep pealing without some other external forces acting on the area.

Comment: Awesome, that's really good to know! I was worried it might peel more. Thanks!